# How can I add React component in the Draft.js and then display it?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I encountered the problem when React element was passing in Draft.js the app is break down, that’s why I convert it in appropriate format `(convertFromRaw)`, then for display editing text I used to dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Give me, please couple solutions to input dynamically data like: paragraph, heading, order list into Draft.js then display styled result on the page, preferable without dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { EditorState, convertFromRaw } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';

const reactElementToContentState = (element) => {
  return convertFromRaw({
    entityMap: {},
    blocks: [
      {
        type: 'unstyled',
        text: element.props.children,
        key: 'foo',
        entityRanges: [],
      },
    ],
  });
};

export const Editors = () => {
  const initialContent = <p>Hello, this is a Draft.js content!</p>;

  const initialContentState = reactElementToContentState(initialContent);

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    EditorState.createWithContent(initialContentState),
  );

  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  const onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    setEditorState(editorState);
  };
  const handleContentStateChange = (contentState) => {
    setState(contentState);
  };

  const contentStateHtml = draftToHtml(state);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 600, border: '1px solid red' }}>
      <div style={{ border: '1px solid' }}>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
          onContentStateChange={handleContentStateChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: contentStateHtml }} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I read these articles to understand what are approaches people use:

- [How to render provided HTML in a draft js editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743149/how-to-render-provided-html-in-a-draft-js-editor?rq=3)
- [How to insert HTML in Draft.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307326/how-to-insert-html-in-draft-js?rq=3)

I tried pass unedited, not stylized React element - expected to see edited, styled.
An additional, to get appropriate format of data for saving in DB in order to use later.